# Recent change to underscore.js has broken Backbone.ModelBinder. How to proceed?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I recently started using Backbone.js (which uses underscore.js) and wanted to supplement using Backbone.ModelBinder  https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder.

It appears that a recent change to the bindAll() method in underscore.js has broken the examples provided with Backbone.ModelBinder.  Apparently, it now throws an exception if no functions are provided in the call.

I have "fixed" the problem by changing one line of code in the constructor:
   `_.bindAll(this);`  is now replaced with
   `_.bindAll.apply(_, [this].concat(_.functions(this)));`
(this was thanks to a thread at https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/commit/bf657be243a075b5e72acc8a83e6f12a564d8f55)

The examples now seem to work but I am wondering if there are other landmines I will encounter?  Would I be better off to revert to a prior version of underscore.js until the good folks at theironcook put out a compatible version of Backbone.ModelBinder?

Comment: I don't know if Modelbinder is actively developed anymore, since has been five months since the last commit. For this reason lately I started a new project and choose [Stickit](http://nytimes.github.com/backbone.stickit/) over Modelbinder. Truth be told, I think that Modelbinder actually is easier to use but Stickit seems more stable to me in the long period.

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? ["If no **methodNames** are provided, all of the object's function properties will be bound to it."]((http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) so `_(this).bindAll()` and `_.bindAll(this)` should still work and [they really do still work](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/bkj8E/).

Comment: mu is too short (interesting moniker!) - the change to underscore.js appears to be very recent (less than 2 weeks ago) so perhaps you are on a version prior to 1.4.4.  The documentation hasn't been updated to reflect the change.

Comment: @Ingro - thanks for the tip; I will check Stickit out